# How to check if a file contains a string and nothing else

Tags: bash

I'm looking for something like diff in bash script, but instead of checking if two files are equal, I can check if the file contents match exactly a specific string. I don't want it to be true if there are other things in the file, but rather, it needs to be an exact match. What's the best way to do this?

Example:

String is: "Hello World"
A file containing "Hello World" and nothing else will satisfy, but one that contains "Hello World, Hello World" will not since it is longer than the string I want to match exactly.

Comment: What part don't you know how to do already? (If you know how to read a file into a string, but not how to compare two strings, that's one thing; if you know how to compare two strings, but not how to read a file into a string, that's another). Alternately, if you already tried something, could you show your work?

Comment: Also, are you reading *text files* (which, to be valid on UNIX, require that each line end with a newline)? If so, do you want that trailing newline to be considered in the comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use `diff` (or `cmp`, if you don't need an accounting of the differences). All you need to do is either create or "fake" a file that contains the string you want to compare with. There are several ways to do that:

- Send the string to `diff` or `cmp` on standard input using a "here string" designated by `<<<`, and use `-` as an argument to let the program know it should be reading from stdin:

  ```
  $ cmp filename - <<<"Hello World"
  ```

  (note that there will be no trailing newline on the "Hello World" passed in this way, unlike some other suggestions below)
- For longer strings that may contain newlines, same thing except use a "here document" introduced by `<<`

  ```
  $ cmp filename - <<EOF
  Hello World
  and here is another line
  EOF
  ```

  (note the `EOF` can be anything, just make sure it's the same at the beginning and end)
- Write the string to a temporary file and use that as the comparison

  ```
  $ TMPFILE=$(mktemp)
  $ echo "Hello World" > "$TMPFILE"
  $ cmp filename "$TMPFILE"
  $ rm "$TMPFILE"
  ```
- Pipe the string to standard input of the comparison program

  ```
  $ echo "Hello World" | cmp filename -
  ```
- Create a "fake" file that will provide the desired text to the comparison program using process substitution

  ```
  $ cmp filename <(echo "Hello World")
  ```